# Yii2: How to do a math addition in a simple find() response?

Tags: php, math, yii2, arithmetic-expressions

I have an array (called **products**) created with the Yii2 **find()** function with two fields (called **name** and **price**) and I need to do a simple arithmetic addition: **price + 5**. But I don't know how to do it.

Using SQL is very easy but with Yii2 I don't know how to resolve it.

```
$products = Products::find()
    ->select([
        'name',
        'price',
        'price' + 5
    ])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is because you need **not to quote the expression** , just use the [`\yii\db\Expression()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-expression) inside your `select()` statement like below

```
$products = Products::find()
    ->select(['name','price',new \yii\db\Expression('price+5')])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

You can even use it to exclude the discount on the price if `price` and `discount` are table fields, see below.

```
$products = Products::find()
    ->select(['name', 'price', new \yii\db\Expression('price - discount')])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

apart from the syntax used above you can  also wrap the whole selet statement inside the `Expression` like

```
->select([new \yii\db\Expression('name, price, price + 5')])
```

Answer (score 1):

Select your column as an extra field: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#selecting-extra-fields

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
->select("name,price, price + 5")
```

Comment: wrong, this wont work and throw SQL exception column `price + 5` not found.